# How to select inside <a> attribute javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to select text "Početna" inside of a  and then change its value to "Home" using json file

```
// HTML part
<li><a class = "pocetnamenu"  href="#pocetna"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Početna</a></li>


 // JS part
const pocetnamenuEl = document.querySelector('.pocetnamenu');

pocetnamenuEl.textContent = data[attr].pocetnamenu;
```

I am unsure where it went wrong

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: @Dan I tried with innerText and textContent not sure

Comment: From where does all these `data[attr].pocetnamenu` coming from? There is no `data` defined anywhere

Comment: Oh, and write code in English, so when posting on SO we can understand meaning of elements

Comment: @Justinas They come from separate .js file 
var data = {
    "en": 
    {
      "pocetnamenu":"Home",

Comment: It is all working with my H3 tags they are selecting properly but I am not sure how to select that menu text in <a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working:

```
pocetnamenuEl.textContent = "test";
```

So I'm pretty sure this underneath isn't right. I guess some code is missing and this is coming from your json file?
Try logging it.

```
data[attr].pocetnamenu
```

Comment: Okey that made it work but what is the way to keep that font awesome icon its removing it

Comment: What do you mean with font awesome icon?

Comment: Pretty much when I change this string it is removing my icon <i class="fas fa-home"></i>Početna</a> and it only leaves "Home" in menu without home icon I want to change Početna to Home not removing icon too

Comment: Is the html code yours? Can you put a <span> tag around the text around the text inside your <a> tag after the <li>?

Comment: Yes I can do that ! Thanks I made it work!

Comment: Great, it's always best to use tags around text, especially in cases like this. Glad you made it work :)